# Who do people ignore the word "how" at the beginning of a question? What should I do with it?

Tags: questions

Example (https://www.quora.com/How-does-depression-kill-people) :

Question: How does depression kills people?

Answer:

> Yes,
>
> It effects quality of life very seriously, even up to death,
>   common form is suicide.

Obviously, the answerer thought that the question was "Does depression kills people?"  Otherwise he would not start his answer with "yes". Besides, since he changed the paragraph and capitalized "it", probably "yes" was his answer.  **It happens all the time.**

Comment: It happens rarely. Perhaps more on the Internet due to people skimming. If this exchange took place in real life the asker would probably balk at "yes" and reply, "No, I said *how*." (Now, that "no" might be interesting...!)

Comment: This is not a question of English.  It's a question **why don't people read the actual question before answering**, which is probably common to every language.

Comment: Keep in mind that in some cultures words translating to *yes* mean understanding, not necessarily affirmation. Based on the answer in your example, it doesn't seem to be written by a native English speaker.